# How to turn sql result to multi-dimensional array dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays

**Here is the query string.**

```
$query = "SELECT t.id, t.assignee, t.owner, 
            d.code, d.status, d.target_completion_date, 
            d.target_extension_date, d.submission_date, d.approval_date,
            d.revision_start_date, d.revision_completion_date, d.message, 
            ty.name, f.orig_name, f.new_name, 
            b.payment_date, b.discount, b.total_cost, b.amount_payed, b.edit_level, 
            b.billing_type, b.pages, b.words
      FROM tasks t
      INNER JOIN details d ON t.detail_id = d.id
      INNER JOIN billing b ON t.billing_id = b.id
      INNER JOIN TYPE ty ON d.document_type_id = ty.id
      INNER JOIN files f ON t.file_id = f.id
      WHERE t.assignee = 'argie1234'";
```

**And this is the array i would like the query result to turn into.**

```
$user = array('allTask'=>array(array('taskid' => 1,
                                     'assignee'=>'argie1234',
                     'owner'=>'austral1000',
                     'details' => array( 'code' => 'E',
                     'status'=>'TC',
                     'targetCompletionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                     'targetExtentionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',    
                     'submissionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                     'approvalDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                     'revisionStartDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                     'revisionCompletionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                     'messageToEditor'=>'Please work on it asap.',
                     'documentType' => 'Thesis'),
                     'file' => array('orig_name' =>'originalname.docx',
                                     'new_name' => 'newname.docx'),
                         'billing'=>array('paymentDate'=>'July 26,2013 12:40',
                          'discount' => '0',
                           'totalRevisionCharge' => '$20.00',
                          'totalAmountPayed' => '$20.00',
                          'revisionLevel' => '1',
                          'chargeType'=> '1',
                          'numPages' => '60',
                          'numWords' => '120,000' ) ),

                  array('taskid' => 12, 
                                  'assignee'=>'argie1234',
                                  'owner'=>'usaroberto',
                  'details' => array( 'code' => 'E',
                  'status'=>'TC',
                  'targetCompletionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                  'targetExtentionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',   
                  'submissionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                  'approvalDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                  'revisionStartDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                  'revisionCompletionDateUTC'=>'1379401200',
                  'messageToEditor'=>'Please work on it asap.',
                  'documentType' => 'Thesis'),
                  'file' => array('orig_name' => 'originalname.docx',
                                 'new_name' => 'newname.docx'),
                          'billing'=>array('paymentDate'=>'July 26,2013 12:40',
                           'discount' => '0',
                           'totalRevisionCharge' => '$20.00',
                           'totalAmountPayed' => '$20.00',
                           'revisionLevel' => '1',
                           'chargeType'=> '1',
                           'numPages' => '60',
                           'numWords' => '120,000' ) ),

    'account' => array( 'username' => 'marooon55',
            'emailadd' => 'marooon@yahoo.com',
            'firstname' => 'Maroon',
            'initial' => 'E',
            'lastname' => 'Young',
            'country' => 'Australia',
            'gender' => 'M',
            'password' =>'360e2801190744a2af74ef6cbfdb963078b59709',
            'activationDate' => '2013-09-13 14:30:34') );
```

How can i create the above array? I sure know how to define multi dimensional array, regretfully though i am having difficulty creating this complex array dynamically. As a beginner i don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you out. Try starting with simple multi dimensional arrays, once you get a hold of it, you can move onto building complex ones. You will then find that the array you want to build is not really difficult than you initially thought it to be.

$mycomplexarray = array('key1' => array('val1', 'val2'),
                         'key2' => array('val3', 'val4' => array('val5', 'val6')
                                   )
                  );

Comment: thank you for the early reply. yes, i'm experimenting and im starting to get the hang of it. it would be of much help if someone will kindly show me the syntax to create that array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the array just as you have here. I'm not gonna write the whole thing out, but something like this...

```
    $result = $mysqli->query($query); // however you query the db is up to you.
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //same as query use your prefered method to fetch
    $user = array('allTask'=>array(array('taskid' => $row['id'],
                                 'assignee'=>$row['assignee'],
                 'owner'=>$row['owner'],
                 'details' => array( 'code' => $row['code'],
                 'status'=>$row['status'],
```

...etc, Hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: i have actually tried this approach but $user['allTask'] is actually an array that holds not only arrays but non-scalar values  holding another arrays and non-scalar values as well. I can't seem to figure out when to use the foreach loop to step through each succeeding arrays and create the arrays at the same time. This solution is ok if $user['allTask'] only contains 1 array (task data that is). thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can easily check if the current item in all tasks needs to be iterated through by checking if the current value is array ie.. if(is_array($value)){foreach($value as $k =>$v){//do stuff}} You can use recursion or since you know how many dimensions you'll have, you can just check that many levels..or iterate when the key is one you expect to contain an array... more than one way to skin a cat as they say.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a structure array first that defines which columns will be stored in a sub array like

```
$struc=array('Id'->0, 'assignee'->0, 'owner'->0, 
            'code'->'detail', 'status'->'detail', 'target_completion_date'->'detail', 
            'target_extension_date'->'detail', 'submission_date'->'detail', 'approval_date'->'detail',
            'revision_start_date'->'detail', 'revision_completion_date'->'detail', 'message'->'detail', 
            'name'->'file', 'orig_name'->'file', 'new_name'->'file', 
            'payment_date'->'billing', 'discount'->'billing', 'total_cost'->'billing', 'amount_payed'->'billing', 'edit_level'->'billing', 'billing_type'->'billing', 'words');
```

In your `while ($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))` loop you can now use this structure to decide whether you want to store an element directly in your target array or whether you want to place it in the subarray named in this structure array. Like

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$arr=array();
while($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  // within result loop: $a is result from mysqli_fetch_assoc()
  $ta=array(); // temp array ...
  foreach ($a as $k => $v){
    if ($struc[$k]) $ta[struc[$k]][$k]=$v;
    else $ta[$k]=$v;
  }
  $arr[]=$ta;  // add to target array 
}
```

This is the complete code, no more is needed. It  was typed up on my iPod, so it is NOT tested yet.

The generated array should be equivalent to your `$user['allTask']` array.

Comment: hey,thanks. i have actually done that already. currently, my problem is how to use those while loops and foreach loop to step through the array(the sql result array) and dynamically create the php array. I just need a sample syntax to do just that.